# Not saving excel with PHPSpreadsheet in symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, phpspreadsheet

I'm using "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.13", can not save updates into uploaded file. I can read data from it but can not save. The other thing to mention I am running it in the `Process` in background.

```php
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx as XlsxWriter;

//read from file
$reader = new Xlsx();
$reader->setLoadSheetsOnly(["Gifts"]);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($file);
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();

for ($row = 5; $row < $highestRow; $row++) {
  $results[] = [
    'id' => $worksheet->getCell('K'.$row)->getValue(),
  ];
}

//write to file
$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($file);
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getSheetByName('Gifts');
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Import Status');
$writer = new XlsxWriter($spreadsheet);
ob_end_clean();
$writer->save($file);
```

If not use `ob_end_clean();` the file is saving corrupt and LibbreOffice cannot open it with `ob_end_clean();` the file is opening but without changes.

The purpose is to create entities in db reading data from Excel, but because the file can be large I want to run it in the background, maybe it is not the best approach but the best I could do for now so the process is as follows:

1. upload file
2. start new process

```php
Process::fromShellCommandline('php /var/www/app/bin/console app:import:excel "'.$file.'"')->start();
```

3. redirect user to another page
4. send an email with a report of imported stuff

All the steps are working fine except saving Excel, when I am opening the uploaded file it does not have any changes, in other question I have found advice like to add `ob_end_clean();` or `die()` it helped at least to open the file without `ob_end_clean();` it shows that it is broken.

Comment: please describe the process. Do I understand correctly, that you upload a file, read it into the Xlsx reader class, modify it and want to write it back... into the same file. Do you have by any chance multiple processes running? Also: I wouldn't try to overwrite files. the `ob_end_clean` shouldn't change a thing. I have this feeling you're omitting stuff. do you return the file?

Comment: okay, to be honest, why in the gods name would you write the status into the excel file and not just either the database or some miniature text file with like `.status` appended to the original filename.  just seems more sensible to me.

Comment: ok, let's ignore the app design :), tell me why are changes not saving to Excel?

Comment: it's a weird phenomenon at least. don't really have an idea though ;o/